# siunitx, threeparttables and table footnotes

Tags: tables, footnotes, siunitx

I am trying to use the `S` option of `siunitx` for table alignment alongside with `threeparttables` for table footnotes, but it looks like that the footnote mark  is flushed left everytime \tnote{} is used.

Is it possible to use both packages together?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont[Kerning=On,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}

\newcommand{\tabnote}[3]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2\tnote{#3}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tpb]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \begin{tabular}{lcSSSSl}
            \toprule
            &&\multicolumn{4}{c}{Pull--out}\\
            \cmidrule{3-6}
            &&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Good Conditions} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Other Conditions}\\
            \cmidrule(r){3-4} \cmidrule(r){5-6}
            && \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{MC 1990}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{MC 2010}} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{MC 1990}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\emph{MC 2010}}\\
            \cmidrule(r){3-3} \cmidrule(r){4-4} \cmidrule(r){5-5} \cmidrule(r){6-6}
            $t_{max}$ & [\si{MPa}] & 2.50          & 2.50          & 1.25          & 1.25          & $\times \sqrt{f_{ck}}$\\
            $t_f$     & [\si{MPa}] & 0.40\tnote{1} & 0.40\tnote{1} & 0.40\tnote{1} & 0.40\tnote{1} & $\times t_{max}$\\
            $s_1$     & [\si{mm}]  & 1.0           & 1.0           & 1.0           & 1.8           & \\
            $s_2$     & [\si{mm}]  & 3.0           & 2.0           & 3.0           & 3.6           & \\
            $a$       & [-]        & 0.40          & 0.40          & 0.40          & 0.40          & \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}\footnotesize
            \item [1] From data analysis.
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's always best to cut down to a _minimal_ example. The use of XeTeX and system fonts is not vital here, so could usefully have been omitted.

Comment: @Joseph You are right, but then I am a XeLaTeX-only user, and you can never be sure if it is totally irrelevant (at least I can't...). Thanx anyway!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a couple of things here. First, you need to set up `siunitx` appropriately:

```
\sisetup{table-align-text-post = false,table-format = 1.2}
```

(Of course, you may need to adjust the `table-format`). Secondly, at least at the moment, you also need to make `\tnote` robust:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\tnote
```